# How do I selecting the list (li) on C# webbrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

From the code of website

```
td class="tdfield_padding">
                <div class="select_menu" id="id_language_top_main"><ul><li class="option_list"><div tabindex="0" class="edit_select wd_select option_selected" id="settings_generalLanguage_select"><div class="sLeft wd_select_l"></div><div class="sBody text wd_select_m" id="id_language" rel="0">English</div>
                <div class="sRight wd_select_r"></div></div><ul class="ul_obj" id="id_languag_li" style="height: 250px;" o_margin_top="2px"><div class="language_scroll">
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi1_select" rel="0"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">English</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi2_select" rel="1"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">Français</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi3_select" rel="2"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">Italiano</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi4_select" rel="3"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">Deutsch</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi5_select" rel="4"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">Español</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi6_select" rel="5"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">简体中文</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi7_select" rel="6"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">繁體中文</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi8_select" rel="7"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">한국어</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi9_select" rel="8"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">日本語</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi10_select" rel="9"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">Русский</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi11_select" rel="10"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">Português</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi12_select" rel="11"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">Čeština</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi13_select" rel="12"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">Nederlands</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi14_select" rel="13"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">Magyar</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi15_select" rel="14"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">Norsk</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi16_select" rel="15"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">Polski</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi17_select" rel="16"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">Svenska</a></li>
                <li id="settings_generalLanguageLi18_select" rel="17"><a onclick="show('settings_generalLanguageSave_button');show('settings_generalLanguageCancel_button')" href="#">Türkçe</a></li></div></ul></li></ul></div>
        </td>
```

I want to select one of them. This is example of the code that I'm using to open the list box.

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("settings_generalLanguage_select").InvokeMember("click"); // It's only open the list
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("settings_generalLanguageLi2_select").InvokeMember("click"); //And this code is nothing happen...
```

Anyone can help me out? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

IE does not raise the onclick event when you call click programmatically.
Use HtmlElement.RaiseEvent to trigger the event handler.

There is no selected state for li. If you want to move the keyboard focus, use HtmlElement.Focus.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you have any idea to let it select?